# ListView not updating correctly

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I'm trying to replace the ListView with new data but this is not behaving as expected. The main focus is on the

```
ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Order(_orders[i]);
          }
```

and

```
_getOrders() async {
    String authToken = await Auth.getAuthToken();

    http.Response response = await http.get(
        API_URL + '?date=' + _formatDate(_activePeriod),
        headers: {'x-auth': authToken});

    var parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);


    setState(() {
      if (parsedJson.runtimeType.toString() != 'List<dynamic>') {
        _orders = [];
      } else {
        _orders = parsedJson;
      }
    });
  }
```

the first render is correct when the app starts but when I call the `_changeMonth` method on Prev/Next button press which, in turn, calls the `_getOrders`, it doesn't reload the ListView after I override the `_orders` variable. 
If the array has more items than the previous then  I see the new items added at the end but the previous (first time rendered) items stay on the screen.
I can correctly see the new data but overriding the `_orders` variable after the API call does not render the new data in the ListView. Do I need to do something more than using the `setState()`?

Full code of main file. `Order` class is defined in other file but I believe it is not required here.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

 class HomeState extends State {
      final DateTime _thisMonth = DateTime.now();
      DateTime _activePeriod = DateTime.now();

  final String app = 'Orders';

  List<dynamic> _orders = [];

  bool isLoggedIn = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Auth.init().then((loggedIn) {
      if (loggedIn) {
        setState(() {
          isLoggedIn = true;
        });
        _getOrders();
      }
    });
  }

  HomeState() {}

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: app,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text(app),
        ),
        body: isLoggedIn
            ? ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Order(_orders[i]);
          },
          itemCount: _orders.length,
        )
            : Auth.showLoginForm(),
        persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[              
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Prev'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _changeMonth(-1);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Next'),
                onPressed: _activePeriod.month == _thisMonth.month
                    ? null
                    : () {
                  _changeMonth(1);
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _changeMonth(int increment) async {
    setState(() {
      _activePeriod =
          DateTime(_activePeriod.year, _activePeriod.month + increment, 1);
      _getOrders();
    });
  }

  _formatDate(DateTime date) {
    return '${date.year}/${date.month}/${date.day}';
  }

  _getOrders() async {
    String authToken = await Auth.getAuthToken();

    http.Response response = await http.get(
        API_URL + '?date=' + _formatDate(_activePeriod),
        headers: {'x-auth': authToken});

    var parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
    //print(parsedJson);// new data appears fine
    setState(() {
      if (parsedJson.runtimeType.toString() != 'List<dynamic>') {
        _orders = [];
      } else {
        _orders = parsedJson;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a key for `Order`

```
// constructor    
Order(..., {Key key}): super(key: key)

// you should use unique key for stateful widgets, otherwise the list rebuild will be incorrect
itemBuilder: (context, i) {
   return Order(_orders[i], Key(_orders[i].id));
},
```

[see article](https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#keys)

> You can use keys to control which widgets the framework matches up
>   with other widgets when a widget rebuilds. By default, the framework
>   matches widgets in the current and previous build according to their
>   runtimeType and the order in which they appear. With keys, the
>   framework requires that the two widgets have the same key as well as
>   the same runtimeType.